# How to send multicast report on virtual interface?

Tags: c, linux, multicast

I want to send multicast report, and the source address is the virtual interface address, how to do that? thank you.

for example:

Interface information:

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:35:00:11:22
          inet addr:192.168.126.100  Bcast:192.168.126.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth0:111  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:35:00:11:22
          inet addr:192.168.200.52  Bcast:192.168.200.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

I want to send multicast report and the source address is 192.168.200.52, how to do that?

My code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct sockaddr_in localSock;
struct ip_mreq group;
int sd;
int datalen;
char databuf[1024];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Create a datagram socket on which to receive. */
    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sd < 0)
    {
        perror("Opening datagram socket error");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Opening datagram socket....OK.\n");
    }

    /* Bind to the proper port number with the IP address */
    /* specified as INADDR_ANY. */
    memset((char *) &localSock, 0, sizeof(localSock));
    localSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    localSock.sin_port = htons(4321);
    localSock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.200.52");;
    if(bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&localSock, sizeof(localSock)))
    {
        perror("Binding datagram socket error");
        close(sd);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Binding datagram socket...OK.\n");
    }

    /* Join the multicast group 226.1.1.1 on the local 203.106.93.94 */
    /* interface. Note that this IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP option must be */
    /* called for each local interface over which the multicast */
    /* datagrams are to be received. */
    group.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("226.1.1.1");
    group.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.200.52");
    if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&group, sizeof(group)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Adding multicast group error");
        close(sd);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Adding multicast group...OK.\n");
    }

    /* Read from the socket. */
    datalen = sizeof(databuf);
    if(read(sd, databuf, datalen) < 0)
    {
        perror("Reading datagram message error");
        close(sd);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Reading datagram message...OK.\n");
        printf("The message from multicast server is: \"%s\"\n", databuf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is exactly is the problem here?  How is this code not working as you expect?

Comment: Is there anyone can help me？

Comment: You need to give us more information for us to help you.  See my last message.